# How does a flash video player become full screen

Tags: javascript, flash, dom, video, subtitle

I'd like to create a little chrome extension which plays subtitles over full-screened videos.

However, I'm not sure how to have chrome developer tools open while a flash video is fullscreened (so that I can see what's happening in the DOM), or even whether flash full screen somehow bypasses the DOM entirely.

Answers to either question (as to using developer tools, or how fullscreen interacts with the DOM) will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Player's native fullscreen happens separate from the DOM. Flash Player actually creates a new application window that is the size of your monitor. As for getting developer tools open during this, a second monitor may help, but the fullscreen Flash Player window might close itself if it is not the active Window.

It is conceivable that the Flash Player is being fullscreened by a fullscreen DOM element, but this is unlikely. If it says "Press esc to exit full screen" then it is fullscreened through Flash PLayer's native fullscreen.

Unfortunately, unless the SWF is being fullscreened with a fullscreen DOM element, I can't think of a way to add subtitles over the fullscreen player, using the DOM.